# Video Testing Tool & Possibility for Automation

Tags: testing, video, automation

I'm trying to figure out the tools we have in market for testing video streaming devices like **Fire TV Stick, Chromecast & Roku Stick.** I have a basic understanding of these video streaming devices and as far as I understood mostly the testing happens with real time devices.

But I'm looking to find any tools/setup which can simulate these devices and perform testing in different platforms (like *TV, STB, Moobile devices*) irrespective Geographical location, and I'm also looking to understand the feasibility for automating the setup too.

I'm trying to search and get some list of tools where I already got to know about the tools like **Witbe, BBT & Stormtest.** But still I'm looking to know some other tools which are currently missing in my view. So please help me and share if you find any.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simulator available for the Roku Devices.